# Convert Timestamp value in Json Format from Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, json, timestamp, struts

I am trying to send request body from Javascript in Json Format to Java which have date too.
From .jsp file

```
<div class="inv-row">
    <span class="labels-alignment inv-label">Invoice Date:&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="text" id="dtPaymentDate"
            style="height: 30px;background-color: #fff; cursor: pointer; max-width: 185px;"
            onblur="dateFieldBlur(this)" class="form-control dp"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ng-model="dtPaymentDate">
        <span class="text-danger fade in" style="width: 100%; float: left; position: relative; margin-top: 5px;">{{paymentDateError}} {{paymentGreaterDueDateError}}</span>
</div>
<div class="inv-row">
    <span class="labels-alignment inv-label">Due Date:&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="text" id="dtDuePaymentDate"
            style="height: 30px;background-color: #fff; cursor: pointer; max-width: 185px;"
            onblur="dateFieldBlur(this)" class="form-control dp"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ng-model="dtDuePaymentDate">
        <span class="text-danger fade in" style="width: 100%; float: left; position: relative; margin-top: 5px;">{{dueDateError}}</span>
</div>
```

.js file

```
jQuery('#dtPaymentDate').val(this.objScope.PaymentDate);
jQuery('#dtDuePaymentDate').val(this.objScope.DueDate);
var reqParams =
{
    userId: this.objScope.userId,
    billingDate : this.objScope.PaymentDate,
    billingDueDate : this.objScope.DueDate          
};
var strFunctionToCall = "javaController.action" + "?" + "action=processFormCall";

this.makeCall(strFunctionToCall, reqParams,this.processFormStartComplete.bind(this), this.processFormStartComplete.bind(this));
```

And variables in Java are which will be initialized with the data of JSON

```
private Timestamp billingDate;
private Timestamp billingDueDate;
```

But I am getting error

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Incompatible types for property setBillingDate
```

Is there any way to resolve this error.

Comment: Please note that JS objects are not "JSON format"

Comment: What type or format do `PaymentDate` and `DueDate` have?

Comment: @deHaar input type is text and placeholder as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @evolutionxbox currently it is implemented as this, and it worked fine. But I have placed JSON dependency in pom.xml and removed hard coded `JSONPopulator.java' file from project. and using dependency file.

Comment: So only day of month, month of year and year… That's not (fully) matching a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) in Java. Most likely the reason why the types are incompatible… Have you tried other Java classes, like a `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: No I have not tried `java.time.LocalDate` but I have tried the method which defined here https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-date-field-in-java-jackson-example.html#axzz7dQdAiXFP but still getting same error.

Comment: I also tried using `@JsonFormat (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")` on variable declaration.

Comment: That's not matching the text and specifically **not** the placeholder from your first comment here. Then it's date and time? Please show everything related to those variables (on Java and JavaScript resp. JSON). [edit] your question and include the information, please.

Comment: Btw. your link (obviously from 2018!) uses `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`… If you can avoid using those classes, avoid them and switch to `java.time`.

Comment: @deHaar I have edited my question, hope that will be useful to help me